# Show keyboard according to font selection ios

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts

I want to create a Alphabet (Character) tracing and  learning app.Which will be multilingual app.The font for different language will be attached in app resource folder. First user select language and fond. According to language selection the keyboard will be shown.Then user enter a character and trace. Is it possible to show keyboard according to language selection.Or I have to create custom keyboard.Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

You have no control over which keyboard gets shown, unless you create a custom one, unfortunately.  If you had control, you might request to show a keyboard that the user has not enabled in their settings and this would cause a problem.  The only keyboards you can request to open are the ones listed in [UIKeyboardType](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIKeyboardType)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Suppose I create a custom keyboard.Then press a character.Can you please inform me that by using which technique I can Trace a character.How can i measure the accuracy of tracing.I have no idea about this. I never did this type of application before.Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a tutorial here -> http://www.raywenderlich.com/1063/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-custom-input-view-tutorial

Comment: It is a tutorial for a custom input view.  That is the best you are getting.  I doubt there is a tutorial for "tracing and learning the alphabet" because it's not likely to help many people.  If you can't find a tutorial for it, then you will have to break down your problem into smaller pieces and isolate the problem more, or consult with someone who specializes in this area.